# How do you center a video using CSS

Tags: css, video, center

I'm trying to center a video within my site but I don't want to use the center tags in HTML because it's kinda obsolete. How do I do this with CSS? Here's my HTML code if it's any help.

```html
<center>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</center>
```

Comment: Kind of obsolete? Very obsolete! Depending on how the page is marked up, you can likely adjust the right/left margins as auto. For example, `video { margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: A post that tackles centering a video vertically and horizontally within a div whilst maximising space and maintaining aspect ratio - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124364/how-can-i-center-a-video-vertically-and-horizontally-within-a-div-whilst-maintai - probably more useful to most people than this post

Answer (score 24):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cn7SU/

Just add these CSS rules to the element `video`:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Add the `display: block` property is very important. Otherwise you can't center the element.

Answer (score 18):

Here are 3 ways to center your video:

## 1. Using margin

```
video {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

## 2. Using transform

```
video {
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

## 3. Using a container & [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.container video {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this topic was so long but here ya go:

This is for the center of the page

```
video {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

And this is for the middle of the line

```
video {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Just for who are looking for this

Answer (score 6):

To center video horizontally add:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, have a wrapper div around your video tag. html5 videos and images are treated like text when styling. So a text-align:center will work. You can check the fiddle below.

```html
<div class="video">  
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Helped me indeed for an embedded YouTube video. Thanks. :)