# How can I center a video vertically and horizontally within a div whilst maintaining aspect ratio and maximizing available space

Tags: html, css, video

I have a div of unknown size (I have used a fixed height in the example but this is for illustration purposes only) and I have a video of unknown size but the video aspect ratio is known (16:9 in this case).

I want to center the video within the div both vertically and horizontally.

I want to use CSS and HTML only if possible. No JavaScript.

The video should always be contained within the div. The video can be stretched or shrunk and should snugly fit within the div BUT ...

It is imperative that the aspect ratio of the video is maintained at all times. Ensuring that this requirement is adhered to:

- the video height should be the same height of the div where possible
- the video width should be the same width of the div where possible

Thus, as the browser is resized, the appearance of the two together should always look like one of the following:

[image]

The first image represents a single `main` div with the same width of the video but a greater height.

The second image represents a single `main` div with the same height of the video but a greater width.

The use of wrapper divs, if required, is fine.

Here's what I have tried so far but it does not work (please excuse my excessive use of wrappers):

```css
div.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div.video-wrapper-1 {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div.video-wrapper-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.video-wrapper-3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.video-wrapper-4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="video-wrapper-1">
    <div class="video-wrapper-2">
      <div class="video-wrapper-3">
        <div class="video-wrapper-4">
          <video autoplay muted controls>
            <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `video { max-width: 100% }`

Comment: many thanks - I've added a full working answer based on your comment. Given that this comment answers the question, if you provide an answer to this question based on this comment I will accept it as the correct answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: a user already answered the same! So no worries - A single comment fixed your problem! that's nice 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `video { max-width: 100% }` or `width: 100% / auto;`. It'll help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kunal Tanwar's comment I got this working! Here's the simplified full working version.

```css
div.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div.video-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <video autoplay muted controls>
      <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use object-fit contain on the video.

I didn’t understand what all the wrappers were for so have removed them.

```css
div.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <video autoplay muted controls>
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Great answer. However, the player controls are displayed funny (at the bottom of the div NOT at the bottom of the video) when the height of the div is greater than the video. However, this may not be a problem if I do not need to display the controls. Maybe u know a fix to get the controls positioned correctly? Either way this is very helpful.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'correctly' - I guess it's up to the system where it puts them if it's asked to show the controls. The alternative is probably to implement your own controls.

Comment: correctly === at the bottom of the video NOT at the bottom of the div

Comment: What system are you using? I can’t get the controls at the bottom of the div.

Comment: Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 - I just run your example and resize the browser to a narrow width to make the div taller than the video - when you do this the controls are at the bottom of the div

Comment: Seen it now thanks. You'll notice that the pink is 'duskier' towards the bottom - that's the system deciding where to put the controls - happens even without the object-fit.